# Authorization Error with LightIngest in Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure, parquet, azure-data-explorer, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to ingest historical data from a **Storage Data Lake Gen2** to a Dabatase in **Azure Data Explorer**. The provided solution is to use a tool **LightIngest** to ingest large amounts of data.

It gives you the command to execute it using the tool **LightIngest.exe**

[image]

```
LightIngest.exe "https://ingest-mycluster.centralus.kusto.windows.net/;Fed=True"
-database:"DataBaseName" -table:"TableName" -source:"https://mydatalake.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?sv=mysas"
-format:"parquet" -prefix:"2022" -pattern:"*" -ingestionMappingRef:"MyMapping" -tag:"XXXX"
```

I downloaded the tool from the URL provided in **Download LightIngest**.

I execute the command but It fails with the following error message:

```
IngestSingle failed: Forbidden (403-Forbidden): {
"error": {
    "code": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Caller is not authorized to perform this action",
    "@type": "Kusto.Common.Svc.Exceptions.UnauthorizedOperationException",
    "@message": "Principal 'aaduser=XXXX;XXXX' is not authorized to perform operation 'Ingest' on 'any database'."
```

It says that the following Principal (which is not my user Object Id from AAD and I don't even recognize that Principal) is not authorized to perform any action in the database.

I also added my user to the database with the following command:

```
.add database DataBaseName users ('aaduser=myemail@email.com') 'User (AAD)'
```

But still getting the error.

Am I missing something? Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

database-user permissions are insufficient for ingesting data into any table in the database. you'll need either table-ingestor permissions, or database-ingestor permissions.

see: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/netfx/kusto-ingest-client-permissions#permissions-on-the-engine-service)

To specify the tenant ID in the connection string, look for "authority ID" in the examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/connection-strings/kusto#authentication-properties-details)

Comment: I just noticed that the Principals shown in the error message is my own User but in another Tenat (Directory). I don't know why is taking that user in the first place since my Cluster is in another Tenant (Directory). Is there a way to specify the User Object Id and or Tentant in the LightIngest command?

Comment: Yes. You can add it all in the cluster connection string, for example UID=, read here for details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/connection-strings/kusto